# how to implement a custom foreach template view method

Tags: php, html, templating, smarty3

I was coding a TemplateView Class which is replacing  `@somevariable@`  placeholders with it's controller set correspondent. ViewHelpers are called via placeholders that simulate a function like  `@headerFiles()@`  for example.

The thing missing is a foreach loop definition like for example the **smarty**
 `{foreach from=$var key=index item=value}` definition.

Until now I was iterating over a database object inside the controller and having a heredok or string concatenation assigned to the view. So there is a lot of `html` inside the controllers which I think should not be the controllers job.

I already implemented smarty into the app for testing and it's working fine - But when I decide to really use it I would have to change so many things like all partial templates would have to be .tpl files and all template directories would have to be merged ? or in one place and so on.

**So my question is:**
Are there any good examples or codesnippets I could use to implement a custom foreach loop method ? Before I have to change everything to use smarty. I also want to avoid using plain php like `<?php foreach(): endforeach; ?>`

**UPDATE:**
what concerns would one have going this direction ?

In a template:

```
 @foreach array@
 if($key !== 'fart'){
    echo $val;
 }
 @endforeach@




class Foreacher  {
    private $template;
    protected $array = array('fart' => 'poop', 'foo', 'bar');

    public function __construct($template){
       $this->template = file_get_contents($template);
    }

    public function parse(){
       if(preg_match_all('/@foreach ([\w]+)@(.*?)@endforeach@/is', $this->template, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
        $var = $matches[0][1];

        $freach = "<?php foreach(\$this->$var as \$key => \$val){";
        $freach .= $matches[0][2];
        $freach .= "} ?>";

        $parsed = str_replace($matches[0][0], $freach, $this->template);
        $this->render($parsed);
       }
    }

    public function __get($var){
      if(isset($this->$var)){
          return $this->$var;
      }
      return null;
    }

    protected function render($string){
       $tmp = tmpfile();
       fwrite($tmp, $string);
       fseek($tmp, 0);
       ob_start();
       $file = stream_get_meta_data($tmp);
       include $file['uri'];
       $data = ob_get_clean();
       fclose($tmp);    
       echo $data;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Interesting question, yet I can't really determine how to answer it without some code. You're right that HTML shouldn't be in your controller; yet it can be delivered by it. There's nothing wrong with using multiple templates (views) with several page views with other helper views. Consider making/using objects with 'view' methods that you can send to your template/views. The 'view' methods could be called from within your page view if needed. Just a thought.

Comment: maybe not a bad idea - you mean like `__toString()` method in the Model ?

Comment: Nah, just view() for a class of object. I do it all the time with Factor patterns. For example, I have a bunch of questions. Some are text, radio, selects, etc. Each class is a type of question, but they all have view() methods. I pass those questions thru to my template view and into my page view, where I then loop thru them and echo $obj->view().

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean but dont see how I could implement the same - the more I think about it I might be better off using smarty because there'd have to be also control structures for displaying content differently for each user. Or could you provide a brief example how you do it?

Comment: I may be getting you off track. If you're limited to using Smarty than look for a smarty solution that fits your needs. Smarty has been out for a long time, so hopefully you can find something that helps. It's been way too long since I've used Smarty.